# In R, how do you add a string or characters to only the first number of rows of the data frame

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I have a date column as such:
id <- c(1, 2, 3) ,
date <- c("4 May 20", "5 June 20", "16 April 2021")

I want to add "20" to the end of the first 2 rows only and create a new column to make the dataframe look like this:

```
id  date               new_date
1   4 May 20           4 May 2020

2   5 June 20        5 June 2020

3   16 April 2021      16 April 2021
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `sub` to match the space (`\\s+`) followed by 2 digits (`\\d{2}`) at the end (`$`) of the string, captured as a grouped (`(...)`) and in the replacement, insert the 20 followed by the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group

```
df1$date <- sub("\\s+(\\d{2})$", " 20\\1", df1$date)
```

---

If the OP wanted to do this only on a subset of rows on the original data i.e. predetermined

```
df1$date[1:10] <- sub("\\s+(\\d{2})$", " 20\\1", df1$date[1:10])
```

-output

```
 df1
  id          date
1  1    4 May 2020
2  2   5 June 2020
3  3 16 April 2021
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3), date = c("4 May 20", "5 June 20", 
"16 April 2021")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L
))
```

Comment: It wasn't exactly what I was looking for but somehow it works.  Thanks.

Comment: @KhanhN I was looking at your expected to answer this.  In your post, it was mentioned for first 2 rows and I found a pattern that those elements have only 2 digits at the end.  thus, used `sub`

Comment: Right.  I was expecting to have a for loop with ifelse statement like this:  for(i in nrow(df)){df[i, "new_date"] <- ifelse(i < 3, paste0(df[i, "date"], '20'), df[i, "date"])}.   I guess my better question is how to add a string to only the first 10 rows in a thousand rows data frame.

Comment: @KhanhN if it first 10, just subset by index `df1$date[1:10] <- sub("\\s+(\\d{2})$", " 20\\1", df1$date[1:10])`

Answer (score 2):

@akrun has answered the question you asked, but if what you're really doing is trying to parse dates, `lubridate::dmy` can handle your problem very easily:

```
library(lubridate)
data$new_date <- dmy(data$date)
data
  id          date   new_date
1  1      4 May 20 2020-05-04
2  2   5 June 2020 2020-06-05
3  3 16 April 2021 2021-04-16
```

Data

```
data <- structure(list(id = 1:3, date = c("4 May 20", "5 June 2020", 
"16 April 2021")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L
))
```